# How to send data from localstorage to backend with jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, jwt

How to send jsonwebtoken from localstorage with jquery to node server. I've tried to do that with this way but it not works. Here is my code from client side for requests handle.

```
$(function () {
    $('.subForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/spec/register',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    location.href="http://localhost:3000/login"
                }else{
                    location.href="http://localhost:3000/signup"
                }
            }  
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

        $('.personAuth').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/person/register',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.success){
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/login"
                    }else{
                        console.log("Chexav");
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/signup";

                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.companyAuth').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/company/register',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.success){
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/login"
                    }else{
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/signup"
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.logInForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data.token){
                        localStorage.setItem("Authorization",data.token);
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'get',
                            url:'http://localhost:3000/users/user',
                            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('auth', localStorage.getItem("Authorization"));},
                            success:location.href="http://localhost:3000/users/user"
                        })
                    }
                }    
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

After authentication route in middleware I want to take token from auth header

```
 router.post('/authenticate', (req, res,next) => {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        Model.findUser(email, (err, user) => {
          if(err) throw err;
          if(!user){
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
          }
          Model.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
              let payload={
                name:user.name,
                email:user.email_num,
                role:user.role,
                deleted:user.deleted,
                isActive:user.isActive,
                created:user.created,
              };
              let token = jwt.sign(payload,config.JWT_SECRET,{
                  expiresIn:1440
              });

                Model.saveToken(email,user.role,token,(err,success)=>{
                    if(err) return err;
                    console.log("Success");
                    // res.cookie('Authorization',token);
                    res.json ({ success: true, token: token });
                }); 


            } else {
              return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
            }
      });
   });
// res.redirect("/user");
 });

 router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // console.log(req.headers);
    let token = req.headers['auth'];
     console.log(typeof(req.headers['auth']));
      if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {      
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
          } else {
            req.decoded = decoded;    
            next();
            // res.render("user");
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({ 
            success: false, 
            message: 'No token provided.' 
        });

      }
    });

router.get("/user", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("user");
});
```

This is model and functions with database

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const Spec = require("./specialist");
const Person = require("./person");
const Company = require("./company");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

module.exports.findUser=function(username,callback){
    let query = {email_num:username};
    Spec.findOne(query,(err_spec,spec_user)=>{
        if(err_spec) throw err_spec;
        if(!spec_user){
            Person.findOne(query,(err_person,person_user)=>{
                if(err_person) throw err_person;
                if(!person_user){
                    Company.findOne(query,(err_company,company_user)=>{
                        if(err_company) throw err_company;
                        if(!company_user){
                            return console.log("Error User Not Found");
                        }
                        return callback(null,company_user);
                    });
                }
                return callback(null,person_user);
            });
        }
        return callback(null,spec_user);
    });
};
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
    });
};
module.exports.saveToken = function(username,role,token,callback){
    let query = {email_num:username};
    let updateToken={updatedToken:token};

    if(role==="Person-User"){
        Person.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
    }else if(role==="Specialist-User"){
        Spec.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
    }else if(role==="Company-User"){
        Company.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
    }else{
        console.log("Something went goes wrong");
    }
}
```

I use mongodb and i have three collections this code I use for handling all of them.

console.log(typeof(req.headers['auth'])) in middleware brings string after that undefined,I cant find the reason for this.Also I know that i can do this with cookies,but I want to do this with another way using only local storage. 
Thanks for help and sorry for language mistakes)))))

Comment: problem is that middleware not works, it cant find token, and brings token not provided

Comment: What is the value of token inside your `saveToken` function? `res.json ({ success: true, token: token });`

Comment: token is string saveToken just function that takes token and send to database and send second parameter(token)which it takes from route ,sorry that i havent explain that function.Thanks for attention!!!!!

Comment: You didn't answer the question... what is the tokens VALUE, not the data type ;)

Comment: Which version of express are you using? In 4.x the way to get the value of a header is req.get('auth') See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiVmF6Z2VuIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ2emdvQG1haWwucnUiLCJyb2xlIjoiU3BlY2lhbGlzdC1Vc2VyIiwiZGVsZXRlZCI6bnVsbCwiaXNBY3RpdmUiOnRydWUsImNyZWF0ZWQiOiIyMDE4LTAxLTA1VDA4OjUzOjU5LjY4N1oiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTUxNDg0NTEsImV4cCI6MTUxNTE0OTg5MX0.cwwhp2Ip5wKP-_hWSy-zAcmwZN-G-xY7Mxk3WXiJbAs  :)))))

Comment: James Bubb I tried that, but it brings the same problem.But thanks )))

Comment: console.log(token) in middleware brings token value and under that undefined.I dont understand whats happening?:((

Comment: Where undefined is print ?

Comment: Your code works, the auth header is well send through the xhr request

Comment: I tried to console.log(token) in middleware which takes from header,it brings like this`
(token value)
undefined

Comment: undefined under token value,but middleware returns token not provided.

Comment: Edit your code to show the failed display. I have tried your code, see in response, it display the good values.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

In server side :

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  let token = req.headers["auth"];

  console.log("Token 1 "+token);
  req.decoded = token;
  return next();
});

router.get("/a", function(req, res){
  console.log("Token 2 "+req.decoded);
  return res.status(200).json({});
});
```

Then send this in front :

```
localStorage.setItem("Authorization","sdfsdf");
$.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:'http://badasse.com/a',
     beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('auth', localStorage.getItem("Authorization"));},
     success:location.href="https://www.google.fr"
});
```

The good values are displayed correctly in the console

Comment: The same problem comes,i tried to console.log(req.headers) and its return 2 values one with auth header and the second witout auth header,thats why console.log(token) returns two values one token second undefined.Its send to requests one with auth header second without.I guess I found where's coming problem,but why i haven't idea.

Comment: OK, i found,that in request handler,with ajax get request i send auth header, but in success property location.href going without auth header, how can i send request location.href="http://localhost:3000/users/user" with auth header.

Comment: You cannot set custom headers if you are redirecting the user to a different page. You have to pass the value through cookies / GET variable or POST variable